# jQuery fire audio

Tags: jquery, html

Is there anything wrong with this code? The audio file doesn't play on loading the webpage.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src','content/audio/tune.mp3');
    audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
    //audioElement.load()
    $.get();
    audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
    audioElement.play();
    }, true);

    audioElement.play();

    });
```

Comment: Oh no please don't downvote! Error while copying the code!

Answer (score 1):

missing one ); in the end I believe. So you close the ready function.